# How to get the data from this url in a react.js web app?

Tags: reactjs, api

URL: http://refertest.pythonanywhere.com/job/openings
Description: The API will fetch the list of job openings with all the details.
Method: GET
Headers:
{
"tid": 3441
}
Response Payload:
{
"statusCode": 0,
"statusMessage": "jobs data fetched successfully"
"data": [
// list of json objects with data for jobs
]
}
Curl:
curl --location --request GET 'http://refertest.pythonanywhere.com/job/openings' 
--header 'tid: 3441'

Comment: Please check "How to ask" first.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) api. See working example in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-benz-o8lvmu?file=/src/App.js:0-955). (Please note that I switched your url to https in my example.) More examples in the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html). See also axios.

Example:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(undefined);
  const [data, setData] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://refertest.pythonanywhere.com/job/openings")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
        setData(json.data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        setError(err.message);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}

      {!loading && error && <div>{error}</div>}

      {!loading && data && (
        <div>
          {data.map((entry) => (
            <div>
              {entry.company} - {entry.designation}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```